# Lista de correções que já sabem que são necessárias

Tags: debate, tradução

Existe um conjunto de erros, coisas que faltam que já muita gente detectou.

Faltas de traduções, traduções que ficam sobrepostas a texto, etc.

A questão que coloco é... Quais os problemas que já conhecem? Não seria bom haver uma lista desses problemas para evitar questões a mais no meta?

Comment: É verdade. Talvez se criarmos um post wiki onde vamos adicionando o que falta traduzir.

Comment: Não é só traduções. São correções como a palavra "visualização" que fica por de tras do texto das perguntas, e outros pormenores que resultam do o site estar em beta :)

Answer (score 5):

O melhor caminho é criar posts aqui no Meta pra cada um deles... O Meta funciona bem como bug report, e nós temos tags pra filtrar o que já foi feito, o que vai ser feito, o que já sabemos, etc...

Answer (score 4):

Eu concordo com o Tiago, me parece pouco prático ficar criando uma publicação para cada vez que houver algum probleminha.

Agora, por exemplo, eu estava revendo as minhas traduções que foram revisadas e aceitas [muito bom ver suas traduções sendo usadas no site!\o/], e observei que em uma delas falta um singelo 'de' ... E na verdade cheguei até esta pergunta enquanto buscava meios de indicar esse errinho.

Não sei se os 'Comments' do Transifex servem para isso também.
Poderíamos criar uma 'pergunta' sobre os erros de tradução e sempre que alguém achasse algum errinho colocaria uma resposta, quando o erro for sanado poderia ser indicado por meio de um comentário. [não é a coisa mais elegante do mundo, mas acho que resolve o problema]

Enquanto isso não me sentirei segura de reportar esse errinho por medo do  [S gigante do Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694)....

Comment: Acho que no caso no transifex (que não era utilizado na época dessa pergunta), você pode simplesmente submeter a tradução corrigida. Imagino que isso mande a tradução diretamente para a fila de revisão, e se for necessário justificar a mudança (pode não ser óbvia), você pode usar os comentários e até marcar como *Issue* para dar mais destaque.

Comment: Você deve ter privilégios a mais do que eu, porque eu não consigo editar uma tradução já revisada. Mandei uma mensagem pro Gabe para ver se posso usar os comentários para indicar traduções com erro, de todo modo, também é preciso algum jeito de pessoas que não estão no projeto de tradução poderem indicar erros.

Comment: Opa, falha minha. Não tenho privilégios a mais, mas não tinha notado que ela fica travada. A aba "Suggestions" fica ativa, mas não sei se uma sugestão gera algum tipo de flag para chamar a atenção dos revisores. Nesse caso acho que o comentário com *issue*  é uma opção mais interessante ainda.