# Múltipla tradução para o mesmo termo

Tags: debate, tradução

Acho que todos os voluntários para tradução passaram por isso: qual o termo mais apropriado?

Teoricamente, o glossário serve para isso, para mostrar a tradução correta para termos-chave. Entretanto, chegamos a 99% de tradução com praticamente nenhuma palavra no glossário [estou adicionando algumas agora].

Acho que seria válido abrirmos uma discussão para palavras com múltipla tradução e assim escolhermos qual vai pro glossário e, assim, quando for necessário traduzir não haverá dúvida. Além de que temos de corrigir as traduções com os termos que não forem escolhidos.

Eis a lista que eu pude encontrar:

- **Close** - encerrar, fechar
- **Delete** - excluir, remover, apagar
- **Post** - publicação, post, postagem
- **Bounty** - recompensa, gratificação [essa foi adicionada ao glossário como recompensa, mas ainda há traduções com 'gratificação']
- **On hold** - suspensa, pendente
- **Log in** - fazer log-in, logar
- **Newsletter** - newsletter, boletim
- **Ban** - proibição, veto, banir/banimento
- **Off topic** - fora de escopo, descontextualizados, fora do assunto
- **Question** - pergunta, questão

PS: as minhas preferencias são as primeiras sugestões que eu listei de cada termo.

Comment: **Off topic** - Fora de escopo, descontextualizados, fora do assunto; **Post**  - + postagem; **Delete** - + apagar; **Ban** - + banir/banimento; **Question** - Pergunta, questão;

Comment: Muito bem visto.

Comment: Bem, vou editando a publicação com as sugestões que aparecerem aqui, e acho que cada usuário poderia dar uma resposta com os termos que preferem. Lembrando que, quem cala consente, se a galera ficar quieta vou arbitrar um nome e colocar [vou tentar pegar o termo mais frequente até agora].

Comment: Acho que já se passou tempo o suficiente para os interessados comentarem. Dito isto, levando em conta as sugestões postas aqui e o bom senso vou atualizar o glossário e comentar os blocos que precisam de 'correção' da tradução.  Comecei com 'Close', e vou fazendo aos poucos para dar chance dos moderadores me banirem por encher a paciência.

Comment: **Undelete** - desfazer remoção, restaurar. (quando se fala em "restaurar uma pergunta" para mim não é claro que é a ação oposta a excluir).

Comment: Comentei todas as traduções inconsistentes que encontrei e coloquei no glossário as traduções 'canônicas'. Resta saber se/quando alguém seguirá essas sugestões.

Answer (score 4):

Em primeiro lugar, parabéns por todo o seu trabalho de tradução. Eu revisei boa parte das suas traduções, e vi que foram muitas, e muito boas, assim como suas contribuições ao glossário.

Quanto à lista que você está debatendo, vou comentar cada item.

- **Close**
  Eu prefiro *fechar*, porque reflete bem o que acontece com a pergunta (não aceita mais respostas). *Encerrar* ([que era mais usado no site inicialmente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/797/close-traduzido-para-encerrar-e-fechar)) passa a ideia de algo definitivo e "resolvido".
- **Delete**
  Também prefiro *excluir*, que é o que vejo na maioria dos aplicativos em português brasileiro. Acontece que isso [soa estranho para os portugueses](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/72/alternativa-a-excluir-para-apagar-um-post), por isso o site acabou adotando *remover*.
- **Post**
  Em geral está sendo usado *publicação* mesmo. Acho esse caso menos sensível, e acho que *post* e *postagem* também são compreensíveis. Não vejo muito problema se, por exemplo, ao clicar em "remover" o sistema perguntar "Deseja mesmo remover essa publicação", mas ao clicar em "sinalizar" ele diga "postagem". Claro que coerência é sempre bom, mas em contextos um pouco diferentes não precisa ser tão rígido. Aliás, tem casos em que pode ser vantajoso usar sinônimos (por exemplo, em textos longos onde uma palavra se repita muito).
- **Bounty**
  Originalmente o sistema dizia *gratificação*, mas [após discussão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/666/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-bounty-seria-melhor-recompensa-ou-gratifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mesmo) o termo mudou para *recompensa*. Portanto, se ainda houver *gratificação* sobrando em algum lugar, isso precisa ser arrumado.
- **On hold**
  Antes o sistema dizia *em suspenso*, mas isso foi [alterado a pedido da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1201/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-r%C3%B3tulo-em-suspenso). Mais tarde, eu (que havia sugerido *suspensa*) repensei e achei a solução ruim, e [ficou mais ou menos decidido que usaríamos *pendente*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2316/suspender-parece-pior-que-fechar). O Gabe chegou até a alterar (na época em que só ele podia editar traduções), mas voltou atrás esperando o novo design do site, que veio com a graduação. Então acho que a tarefa agora é mudar todo para *pendente*.
- **Log in**
  Não sei justificar, mas prefiro *login*, tudo junto, como substantivo. Para o verbo, eu usaria *fazer login*.
- **Newsletter**
  Acho que todo mundo entende *newsletter*, em inglês mesmo. Mas não tenho nada contra *boletim*, se a comunidade preferir.
- **Ban**
  Os *bans* do sistema geralmente são reversíveis, então eu não usaria *banimento* (que me passa a ideia de algo irreversível). O termo *proibição* parece funcionar bem em todos os casos (*question ban*, *review ban*, *suggested edit ban*, etc). Vai ficar tudo meio comprido, espero que não cause problemas de *layout*.
- **Off-topic**
  Antigamente o sistema usava *descontextualizado*, [que é horrível](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256/descontextualizado-%C3%A9-uma-p%C3%A9ssima-tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-off-topic). A votação sobre esse assunto, hoje, está com mais votos para o uso do original em inglês, seguido pelo atual *fora de/do contexto*.
- **Question**
  Esse caso nós nunca debatemos antes, mas acho *pergunta*, que sempre usamos, bem melhor que *questão*. Se for um debate polêmico, poderíamos abrir uma discussão à parte aqui no meta, e colocar em votação.

<sub>Nota: discussões como esta são sempre bem-vindas. Por uma questão de organização, porém, não recomendo seguir editando essa pergunta e incluindo novos itens. Isso invalidaria qualquer resposta já existente no momento da edição, e tornaria o debate difícil de acompanhar. Novos itens podem ser postados em pequenos lotes como você fez, ou mesmo individualmente – e [ninguém virá atrás de você com um S gigante](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3870/74), pode ficar tranquila. Pessoalmente, eu prefiro cada item numa discussão separada, acho mais fácil de acompanhar (veja como alguns dos itens que você citou até já tinham discussões prévias, às vezes não tão curtas).</sub>

Comment: Em 1º lugar, obrigada. Em 2º lugar confesso que foi falha minha não ter 'linkado' às discussões a respeito, mas o fato é que estas foram as palavras que eu anotei enquanto ia traduzindo. E no final das contas, mesmo que haja consenso (entre os gatos pingados que se manisfestaram) a respeito de alguns termos, todos os que eu coloquei foi por ter verificado que estavam com múltiplas traduções atualmente. E como não há como editar/comentar/tocar nos blocos já revisados, esse foi o melhor jeito que achei de indicar termos que precisam ser revistos sem ter de criar um milhão de publicações.

Comment: Se só fossem os S's alheios, vá; uma pessoa acostuma-se às ameaças dos outros; mas quem se incomoda com toneladas de posts sou eu mesma, e este incomodo é tudo.

Answer (score 1):

Do ponto de vista do português do Brasil, minha sugestão:

- **Close** - fechar
- **Delete** - excluir
- **Post** - post
- **Bounty** - recompensa
- **On hold** - em espera (no sentido de estar em análise)
- **Log in** - login
- **Newsletter** - newsletter
- **Ban** - banir
- **Off topic** - "fora de escopo" ou "off topic"
- **Question** - pergunta

Comment: Concordo com quase tudo (estou preparando uma resposta comentando cada item).

Comment: Só com relação ao log in eu me referia ao verbo, mas enfim. E na verdade, as minhas 'preferências' foram baseadas na comodidade/preguiça, simplesmente peguei o termo que eu achei ser o mais usado para limitar as mudanças a serem feitas. No caso do Close, p.ex.,  acho que metade está como encerrar, mas enfim também.